# Inserting data from one table to another in a database(different servers)

Tags: c#, sql

I am using c#(newbee at it) to open connections from one database in a server and migrate it to another database in a different server. This sounds easy but im getting this weird error. Any help ?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"SERVER=fisymsql02.i.ftvac;DATABASE=fcpdp_new;UID=;PWD=");
            thisConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
            thisCommand.CommandText = "select [curfrom],[curto],[rateDate],[rate] from [fcpdp_new].[dbo].[latestxrates]";
            SqlDataReader thisReader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();
            SqlConnection thisConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"SERVER=SBKFISDDB1;DATABASE=UniversalTool;UID=;PWD=");
            thisConnection1.Open();
            SqlCommand thisCommand1 = thisConnection1.CreateCommand();

            while (thisReader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", thisReader["curfrom"], thisReader["rate"]);
                thisCommand1.CommandText = " BEGIN TRY INSERT INTO [dbo].[CurrencyConversionSource]([ToCurrency] ,[FromCurrency] ,[DateTimeStamp] ,[FISClose]) VALUES ("+thisReader["curfrom"] +"," + thisReader["curto"]+","+thisReader["rateDate"]+"," + thisReader["rate"] +") END TRY BEGIN CATCH PRINT 'Error: Same set of primary key; row skipped' END CATCH)";
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(thisCommand1.CommandText, thisConnection1))
                {  
                    **thisCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();**
                    Console.WriteLine("Row inserted !! ");
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            thisConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And I get the following error when I execute this :

" The name "GBP" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

> Incorrect syntax near ')'."

GBP is a valid data from the first row and its not one of the column names. Any ideas ?
The code in ** is where I get the error.

Comment: Hint: When you get stuff like that, have a look at the command text you submit in the debugger and copy / paste it for example into management studio. What you ahve here is a SIMPLE "Oh, the string I create is not right" thing, made more complex by you not using the string.format method (which would make the string construction easier). You basically ask us to fix a simple sql issue here, but you fail to do basic debugging - and thus seeing it.

Comment: Consider using parameters in your query, rather than constructing it all yourself. It's safer, it's marginally quicker in SQL: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an unnecessary `)` at the end of this line;

```
thisCommand1.CommandText = @" BEGIN TRY INSERT INTO [dbo].[CurrencyConversionSource]([ToCurrency] ,[FromCurrency] ,[DateTimeStamp] ,[FISClose])
                             VALUES ('"+thisReader["curfrom"] +"','" + thisReader["curto"]+"','"+thisReader["rateDate"]+"','" + thisReader["rate"] +"')
                             END TRY BEGIN CATCH PRINT 'Error: Same set of primary key;
                             row skipped' END CATCH)";
                                                  ^^^^ here
```

Remove it.

Also you should use single quotes with your `VALUES` strings.

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: that was stupid, anyhow I removed it and I still get this - "The name "GBP" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted."

Comment: @KuberKaul Also you need to use single quotes with your `VALUES` strings. Updated my answer. Take a look at.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Soner's answer, you need to surround string values with single-quotes, otherwise it will be recognized as column name instead of string value, for example :

```
thisCommand1.CommandText = 
            "INSERT INTO [dbo].[CurrencyConversionSource]([ToCurrency]) VALUES ('"
                +thisReader["curfrom"] +"')" ;
```

Furthermore, do it with better approach, parameterized query, instead of concatenating values in query string. Simplified example :

```
thisCommand1.CommandText = 
            "INSERT INTO [dbo].[CurrencyConversionSource]([ToCurrency]) VALUES (@ToCurrency)" ;
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(thisCommand1.CommandText, thisConnection1))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToCurrency", thisReader["curfrom"]);
    thisCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Row inserted !! ");
}
```

Comment: ahhh, I changed it and I get this now - " There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement."


--> New thisCommand1.CommandText = " BEGIN TRY INSERT INTO [dbo].[CurrencyConversionSource]([ToCurrency] ,[FromCurrency] ,[DateTimeStamp] ,[FISClose]) VALUES ('"+thisReader["curfrom"] +"," + thisReader["curto"]+","+thisReader["rateDate"]+"," + thisReader["rate"] +"') END TRY BEGIN CATCH PRINT 'Error: Same set of primary key; row skipped' END CATCH" ;